# Getting java.util.NoSuchElementException when trying to do POST to server. The answer from server is 204/success, but exception is still raised

Tags: android, retrofit2

I doing POST to my server. The result is 204 / Success code, the body for the result is empty. java.util.NoSuchElementException is raised right after the result from server. My guess is that is because the respond contains no body (Void), but I am very unsure

My interface

```
    @POST("register/")
    fun register(@Body phone: PhoneBody): Single<Void>
```

PhoneBody 
`data class PhoneBody(val phone: String)`

My query

```
  disposable += registrationRepository.register(phone)
            .addSchedulers()
            .doOnSubscribe { viewState.showLoading() }
            .doAfterTerminate { viewState.hideLoading() }
            .subscribe({it ->
                Log.d("PAPDEB", "$it Personal Acc Presenter")

            }, this::handleError)
```

it never goes to in-subscribe lambda, it goes right into this::handle which is

```
        if (t is ApiException) {
            viewState.showError(t.message)
        } else if (t is IOException) {
            viewState.showError("No internet connection")
        }

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            t.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://.../register/
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 24
D/OkHttp: {"phone":"+79090000000"}
D/OkHttp: --> END POST (24-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 204 https://.../register/ (386ms)
D/OkHttp: server: nginx/1.13.12
D/OkHttp: date: Tue, 25 Jun 2019 20:52:49 GMT
D/OkHttp: vary: Accept, Accept-Language, Cookie, Origin
D/OkHttp: allow: POST, OPTIONS
D/OkHttp: x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
D/OkHttp: content-language: ru
D/OkHttp: strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP

W/System.err: java.util.NoSuchElementException
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle$SingleElementObserver.onComplete(ObservableSingleSingle.java:111)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onComplete(BodyObservable.java:66)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:48)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12246)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12246)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableSingleSingle.java:35)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3575)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I would be very thankful to hear any ideas of what is wrong and how to get to lambda

Comment: `Single<Void>` seems odd for Kotlin. Perhaps try `Completable`. If it has to be a `Single` for some reason, try `Single<Unit>`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh, well, now I feel very stupid because it actually solved the problem. I changed Single<Void> to Completable. The change to Single<Unit> didn't help. Maybe you should write it as answer then! Thank you!

Comment: I recommend that you answer your own question, showing which of my suggestions worked in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CommonsWare said in the comment to the question the problem was that I used Single (from logic of ctrl+c ctrl+V -> change return model) I changed it to Completable and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2867

Using Completable is one of the way out but if the response will sometime carry data you wanted to keep it using `Single<T>` you can add the Interceptor to your okhttpclient. All credits goes to `jgavazzisp` and `LouisCAD`.

Interceptor

```
    class EmptyBodyInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
        if (response.isSuccessful.not() || response.code().let { it != 204 && it != 205 }) {
            return response
        }

        if ((response.body()?.contentLength() ?: -1) > 0) {
            return response.newBuilder().code(200).build()
        }

        val emptyBody = ResponseBody.create(MediaType.get("application/json"), "{}")

        return response
                .newBuilder()
                .code(200)
                .body(emptyBody)
                .build()
    }
}
```

use on OkHttpClient

```
private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient by lazy { OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .addInterceptor(EmptyBodyInterceptor()).build() }

private var retrofit : Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().client(okHttpClient).build()
```